# Freeform shape moseover event Excel

Tags: vba, excel, events, svg

I'm trying to create a nice user interface in excel. I have the following picture that I'm trying to emulate[image]
And I would like to light up certain elements when I hover over them like this[image] (I'm sure you've seen something similar before, just maybe not in Excel!)

I'm in the process of drawing things up now; I need the whole interface to be resizeable, and because of the complexity of the shapes like the toolbar in the image I'm intending to use either:

- Groups of MSO standard shapes
- A "Freeform" MSO shape
- .SVG vector graphics

This shape complexity is really what leads to the problem - namely that my current solution is to use a transparent activeX label to pick up `MouseMove` events (and another bigger one in the background to capture when the mouse moves away). The invisible label is placed over my visible shape to create the illusion that the shape is picking up the mouseover, see code and image below.

```
Private Sub Label1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
flushHighlight 'remove any existing highlght
setHighlight "shp_1" 'then apply highlight to the shape behind Label1
End Sub

Private Sub Label2_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
flushHighlight
setHighlight "shp_2"
End Sub

Private Sub Label3_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
flushHighlight 'remove highlighting when focus moves away from either shape 
End Sub

Sub setHighlight(shpName As String)
Dim shp As Shape
Set shp = Me.Shapes(shpName)
shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'red "highlight"
End Sub

Sub flushHighlight()
Dim shp1 As Shape, shp2 As Shape
Set shp1 = Me.Shapes("shp_1")
Set shp2 = Me.Shapes("shp_2")
shp1.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(100, 100, 255)'blue "normal" state
shp2.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(100, 100, 255)
End Sub
```

[image: Eg Gif]

The problem with this method (as you can just see at the end of the gif) is that the labels are rectangular, so any rounded corners on the shape result in highlighting when the mouse isn't actually over the shape. Especially when using even more complex compound shapes like the toolbar in my example, I would have to resort to loads of overlapping rectangle labels, the approach is laggy enough already!

So is there another way?

- Maybe svg files can use different events in VBA?
- Maybe there's is an event for MSO shapes/groups/Freeform shapes
- Maybe you can make a custom activeX control (`insert->activex->more controls->register custom` sounds promising)
- Maybe an approach to tracking the mouse directly would work?

Comment: Excel is spreadsheet software so maybe something else than Excel could be used here to create the nice UI?

Comment: @dee I appreciate that there's definitely a better tool for this job. However, I 1) don't know how to use it whatever it is, and 2) Need a spreadsheet software as the back end of this application anyway. In fact the front end too because users enter data in a tabular format that Excel lends itself to quite nicely. But if you know of a way of getting the UI into excel and under the overarching control of VBA (even if the inner workings are with some other language), then that *would* be a solution to the problem.

Comment: Perhaps you could do something smart by reading the pixel colour underneath the mousepointer? http://www.codeguru.com/vb/gen/vb_graphics/article.php/c2357/A-method-to-get-the-pixel-color-under-the-mouse-pointer.htm

Comment: E.g. VSTO and WPF? Google for `vsto for excel`. Then see e.g. [Using WPF Controls in Office Solutions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772076.aspx). But it will require a lot of study. On the other hand to create it in Excel is not easy. IMO Excel doesn't suit for such tasks with rich UI.

Comment: Would be easier to do it in a userform.

Comment: @PatrickLepelletier What are you suggesting? Can I make a wiggly shape on a userform witha `MouseOver` event, or a freeform userform? It could then be set to non-modal and anchored in place to act like the shapes.